# Django: Why are quotes around the model in a ForeignKey definition

Tags: django

I want to know what the difference between these two foreignkey definitions are.

```
(1) MyFKField = models.ForeignKey('MyModel')
(2) MyFKField = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

I understand (I think...) that (1) `MyModel` needs to be defined in that same file and the other needs to be imported, but I'm unsure of the reason/benifits of doing it either way.

I had a look through the Django docs but couldnt find anything, and Im also not sure if this is the right place to ask, so apologies if not.

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) states that you would use a string to (1):

- You want a recursive relationship (eg - `model.ForeignKey('self')`)
- For referring to a model that is possibly not defined yet (for cyclic relationships).
- A shortcut to refer to a model in another application (eg - `model.ForeignKey('app.mymodel')`)

But in general, specifying the model class directly is clear where it's coming from (2).

Answer (score 13):

Without quotes, it's a reference to a model either defined within the file or imported via `import`. With quotes, Django is made responsible for finding the model among all the models in all installed apps.

Comment: Does that mean with quotes, you dont need to import the model?

Comment: Yes. But it takes a (very) little longer for Django to resolve it rather than having Python do it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Would you happen to know if this is still the case. If so why does the django documentation use the quoted version?

Comment: @A.K.S.H.: I couldn't tell you what the documentation writers were thinking.

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of class MyModel is under the definition of class MyFKField (in the code) then you should write it between quotes.